# Problem with fluid type domain & fluid object type inflow

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine, mantaflow

I baked mesh and data both, water(fluid) simulation in domain and fluid flow from plane objects was working fine until i rendered an animation out of it and closed Blender

The next day when I came to carry on again it has become something like hard mesh of cube like this in img and fluid isn't flowing through plane objects.

I know that to make fluid object work *Flow* type object must be inside *Domain* cube but I made it small mistakenly but after that I haven't touched bake mesh & bake data properties.

Haven't touch that properties in white box in image after resizing domain mistakenly.

[image: [![enter image description here][1]][1]]

Comment: I know this might sound stupid, but i've had something similar happen before. By any chance, does dragging your frame indicator back to 0 then replaying the animation fix things?

Comment: naah...bro it didn't [water simulation still not working rest of the animation working fine] actually , but by baking mesh & data again everything works fine but still can't we solve that problem by not doing baking again & again???? but this problem generally occurs when we move or drag the domain cube or any other thing like inflow/geometry fluid objects from the place where it got baked but only until confirming the next location.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/utocRKm check this out but in the case of that blue box over there...it got completely frozen no matter u move it/play animation it will remain like a frozen ice cube until u free data & bake data again.